# My numpy arrays show long error message ending in "AttributeError: 'FloatFormat' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, attributes

For context: I am using the Py app on iPhone which runs and displays code.
What baffles me is when my code stated the following:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([1,2,3])

two_level = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])

print(two_level)

print(two_level[0,3])

print(two_level.ndim)

print(two_level.shape)

print(two_level.size)

a = np.ones((3,2))

print(a)
```

Everything ran appropriately and as normal. Then, I added these lines:

```
c = np.zeroes((2,3))

print(c)
```

Everything about two_level printed fine, then instead of printing c OR a it then gave me several paragraphs of green text along the lines of :

```
File "string", line 11, in module 
File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B96C5A02-913D-4CBE-BE73-9B0912C447FA/Python.app/otherscripts/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1869, in array_str
```

...and so on. I realized "zeroes" was actually "zeros" and corrected this and ran it again. But it came with the same error message (except the part about not finding "zeroes"). Then I erased the part of my code in regards to c, running only the code that had worked before without error messages. The same thing happened as with c included and two_level printed fine, but a did not print and resulted in the same long error message.

Being that the same code that had previously worked now does not work, did I break something? I am confused as to what is going on...

Comment: Part of the error message contains `File "string"`. Do you have any script named `string`? If so, rename it and try again (after restarting Python). It is a bad practice to have variables/scripts named like python built-in objects or modules.

Comment: Nothing I've made was named string, at least not that I can remember.

Answer (score 0):

Update: the app I'm using to run the code just can't run very large files without crashing.